# change azure virtual machine operating system from windows to ubuntu. How I can change OS?

Tags: azure, operating-system, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have problem. I need to change my **microsoft azure** virtual machine operating system. I had a *windows vm template* , so what i need to write in a code ( Json) to change OS ??? Or some other ways (portal , powershell ect) ? Thanks for help me)

P.s my English is bad i`m sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a Microsoft Azure virtual machine. (For more information, see KB [401499](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4014997)7.)

Instead, you should create a new Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the operating system that is required and then migrate the workload.

Instructions for how to migrate Windows Server roles and features are available in the following TechNet topic:
[Install, use, and remove Windows Server migration tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134202)